# Access MySQL from TomCat webservice - No suitable driver found for

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc, tomcat7

I got a WAR-file for a working webservice, which accesses MySQL through JDBC hosted in TomCat 7.

Code:

```
 private static final String db_jdbc_connection = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsea";
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_jdbc_connection, "root, "secret");
```

However, this causes the following error:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsea
  [ERROR] Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method clientSignUp
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In the web-inf/LIB folder of the webservice the following JAR-file is present:

> mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar

Also tried copying this file to tomcat/lib folder.

MySQL is configured with database jsea and the users provided in the connection have permissions.

In MySQL log I see no entries at all.

I have Googled for hours now and I have really no clue. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: It depends on your build process,  I build the wars with included lib library (webapps dir) , not web-inf

Comment: WAR-file is working on other servers (other development machine, production server). Why not on mine? And, if I put JAR-file in root-folder/lib it should work anyway, right? I am new to Tomcat/WAR/Eclipse, so perhaps I am wrong....

Answer (score 1):

No suitable driver" usually means that the JDBC URL you've supplied to connect has incorrect syntax or when the driver isn't loaded at all.

When the method getConnection is called, the `DriverManager` will attempt to locate a suitable driver from amongst those loaded at initialization and those loaded explicitly using the same classloader as the current applet or application.(using `Class.forName()`)

I would suggest to place `mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar` at `/WEB-INF/lib` directory of your project and restart Tomcat. Also, Check Tomcat **logs**, you should find something unusual.

Comment: Thanks, but the JAR-file is already in /WEB-INF/lib. In Tomcat logs I can't find anything, above error is because of try-catch { e.printStackTrace } in the code. I have even tried to import WAR into Eclipse: Same error....

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea what has caused the problem. I have received the source code of the webservice, cleaned the project, rebuilt, and it suddenly works....